# is there a way to set encoding when writing with RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, android, encoding, character-encoding

I open a text file using *windows-1251* encoding

```
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                "windows-1251"));
```

and later write the changes like:

```
  RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(new File(path), "rw");
        try {
            file.write(etMainView.getText().toString().getBytes());
            file.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Changes saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
                        //..... Exception handling
```

The problem is that it messes up all the non-latin letters in the file and when I open it again, all such letters are replaced with some unreadable characters. I guess the `RandomAccessFile` uses UTF-8 by default which is causing troubles. How can I save the file keeping the encoding I used to open it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.getBytes("windows-1251")` instead of `.getBytes()`; `.getBytes()` uses the default JVM encoding.

Comment: oh, just that simple.. had to pay attention to method description. It solves the issue, thanks

Comment: No problem ;) By curiosity, why not UTF-8?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but UTF-8 messes up any text with Cyrillic letters, I had pretty much the same issue opening the file and found some post that suggested to use windows-1251, then it worked.

Comment: That is strange, UTF-8 can encode these without problem... Lack of support on the terminal it seems. Using Windows?

Comment: Yep. I used UTF-8 many times in my apps which support Cyrillic letters, all worked fine. However I didn't try to read and modify text files

Comment: Heh, Windows has notoriously bad UTF-8 support; Notepad and Excel among others expect a BOM in order to read UTF-8.

Comment: just figured out that using windows-1251 works with latin and cyrillic letters, but ignores German characters like ö ü ä.. Can you suggest any workaround to read/write any language text?

Comment: Well, UTF-8... Seriously... Which programs do you use which can't read it? Excel? Notepad?

Comment: actually my own little reader as a part of a more complex app :) I posted the code how I read the file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the stream apis you can do it this way

```
RandomAccessFile file = ....;
FileChannel fc = file.getChannel();
OutputStream os = Channels.newOutputStream(fc);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "windows-1251");
osw.write("Some sring");

osw.flush();
file.close();
```